# Select JToken by property value

Tags: c#, json, json.net, json-deserialization

I am trying to find a more elegant solution than `foreach` loops for the following problem.

Sample JSON Structure:

```
[{
  "OpportunityId": "ABC-123-XYZ",
  "Status": "Active",
  "Milestones": {
    "Milestone": [
      {
        "Name": "Award",
        "Date": "8\/27\/2021"
      }
    ]
  },
  "Staff": {
    "Pocs": [
      {
        "Role": "Development Lead",
        "Name": "Doe, John",
        "Email": "john.doe@company.com"
      },
      {
        "Role": "Capture Manager",
        "Name": "Doe, Jane",
        "Email": "jane.doe@company.com"
      }
    ]
  }
}]
```

I can get the data I want using the following:

```cs
string json = [see above];
JArray? obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(json);

foreach (var single in obj)
{
    JToken? pocs = single.Value<JToken>("Staff")?.Value<JToken>("Pocs");
    if (pocs != null)
    {
       foreach(var poc in pocs)
       {
           if (poc.Value<string>("Role") == "Capture Manager")
           {
               [Do something with the resulting JToken/values]
           }
       }
    }
}
```

I feel like there has to be some Linq to help me here, but everything I've tried thus far has been unsuccessful. I have no control over the JSON input, I just need to deal with it as is. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Seems to me you have working and readable code. Sure you could probably distill it into a few lines of Linq but it’s not going to be more efficient and it will be less readable?

Comment: Have you looked at JSONPath?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by @gunr2171 in the comment, you can work with JSON Path.

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

JArray jArray = JArray.Parse(json);
IEnumerable<JToken> jTokens = jArray.SelectTokens("$..Staff.Pocs[?(@.Role == 'Capture Manager')]");
```

The above JSON Path:

`$` - From root element.

`..Staff` - Deep scan the element node with the `Staff` field.

`.Pocs` - Access to the dot-notated `Pocs` child.

`[?(<expression>)]` - Filter expression.

`@.Role == 'Capture Manager'` - Current node with the filter expression that matches the `Role` field value equal to "Capture Manager".

Reference:

1. [Querying JSON with complex JSON Path](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm)
2. [Cheatsheet for JSON Path](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath)

---

Working with *System.Linq* and *Newtonsoft.Json.Linq*.

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

IEnumerable<JToken> jTokens = jArray.Children()
                .Values("Staff")
                .SelectMany(x => x["Pocs"])
                .Where(x => x.SelectToken("Role").Value<string>() == "Capture Manager")
                .ToList()
```

Comment: [Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6doqGK)

Answer (score 2):

you can try this

```
var jArr = JArray.Parse(json);

JObject person = (JObject) jArr.Children()
          .Values("Staff")["Pocs"].First()
          .Where(s =>  (string)s["Role"]== "Capture Manager")
          .FirstOrDefault();

string name = (string)person["Name"]; // "Doe, Jane"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always create a POCO and deserialize the JToken to that class object. This would allow you to create an array of that POCO from the JToken and use regular linq statements to work with it. It would take a bit more effort, but it might be easier to work with.